# Is there a way to store annotation in a different file?

Tags: pdf, itext, pdftron

I am trying with PDF annotation. I am wondering if it is possible to store annotation in a different file. Say, I have a.pdf, and I added some annotation and store it in b?

Comment: It is technically possible but I doubt there is a proper interface in standard PDF libraries, as it's quite a non-standard requirement.

Comment: Here's a great overview linked to how XFDF is structured and how such API could look like: https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/importing-exporting/xfdf-support/

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. The PDF standard defines two file formats to store annotations in a standard, PDF ISO, compliant way.

The first is FDF (Forms Data Format) which is technically a PDF file, but with no pages, just annotations. This is a binary format.

The second, is XFDF, which is a XML subset of a FDF file. This format is useful since it is standard XML, and can be handled/parsed/edited by any standard XML library. For example, you could store XFDF directly in a SQL database (as a string).

PDFTron PDFNet can import/export both of these formats, on mobile/desktop/server/web, with bindings in C++/Java/C#/VB/Python/Ruby/PHP/Objective-C/Swift.